# Disable a Form while Another Form shows in Qt

Tags: forms, qt

I would like that the main form would disable itselft while I show a secondary form.
I know I could just use `this->setEnabled = false;`, but how can I know when the secondary form is closed? (To re-enable the main form).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want the second form to be a modal dialog? Put it into a QDialog, that blocks the first form automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I just changed my `windowModality` in my secondary dialogs to `WindowModal`, it worked perfectly, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

main widget

```
QChildWidget *child = new QChildWidget();
connect(child,SIGNAL(closed()),this,SLOT(childClosed())); //connect child signal to childClosed slot
child->show(); // show child
this->setEnabled(false); // disable main widget

.
.
.
public QMainWidget::childClosed() // implementation of childClosed slot
{
    this->setEnabled(true);
}

child widget

#include <QCloseEvent>
public QChildWidget: public QWidget
{
.
.
.
protected:
      void closeEvent() // it is called when widget is closed
      {
          emit closed();
      }
signals:
        void closed(); // closed signal
};
```